# Django QueryDict Result Structure

Tags: django

What is resulting querydict structure from a post in django?  Here is an example for a radio button.

A single key in the QueryDict:

```
u'Q1', [u' ', u'1', u' ']
```

In the list for Q1 position 1 is the selected value, what are positions 0 and 2 representing? Here is another example for  "select/drop down" type HTML input.  What do the positions represent here? Position 2 is now the response but what are positions 0 and 1?

```
u'Q6', [u'1', u'1', u'4']
```

What about a text field?

```
u'Q8', [u'', u'', u'Joe']
```

I've looked through the documentation and haven't found the answer or I'm blinding looking right past it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you put three similar django forms inside the single `<form>` tag:

```
<form method="POST">    
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ form }}
    {{ form }}    
</form>
```

If you want to output several instances of the same form class then consider to use the [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) argument in the form constructor or even the [formsets mechanizm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Hum, I'm not actually using forms in that fashion.

Comment: I'm generating a form on the fly based on a dict that passed in.  http://pastebin.com/1gzuKsUV

Comment: Here is an example generated form.  http://pastebin.com/DzpKLG5x.  Note I took out the validation here as I try and get the basic working.

Comment: The cause of the problem is the same - you output hidden fields with the same names as the visible inputs.  So browser sends both hidden and visible values and django accepts them as a list..

Comment: That appears to be the issue!  I appreciate the input.